# Selenium <> AgGrid Multiple Arrow Down using Action class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ag-grid

I am using Selenium with AgGrid (https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php)

[image]

I am trying to select the In Range option from the Total Winnings drop-down using the code below, I was wondering if there is a better way to repeat the sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) instead of mentioning it again and again in a chain i.e. something like sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform(6) (to be honest I didn't find anything in the API).

```
System.out.println("Select the Column");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed'][@aria-colindex='10']//span")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ag-wrapper ag-picker-field-wrapper']")).click();

            Actions actionObject = new Actions(driver);
      actionObject.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

The above code is working and does perform the action however, just wondering if there's a better way to code this.

Answer (score 0):

When the popup is rendered, you can rely on the role attribute of that popup, which is 'option'.

You can use this XPath query to select options inside the filter options popup:

```
let selectOptionQuery = '//div[@role="option" and contains(.,"In range")]';
```

I've created a simple example which selects the 'In range' option at the click of a button: https://plnkr.co/edit/S7A4EguRWmTjjl7g?preview